Upgraded Ansible with Python 3.8 but playbooks are now way slower that with python2.7, how to address slowdown?
When we were running RHEL7 our playbooks used to complete in about 1 hour with ansible-2.9.27-1.el7.noarch.rpm w/ python 2.7 + mitogen.
Last year we upgraded to RHEL8 w/ python 3.8 and ansible-5.4 + mitogen 0.3.5 (w/ support for python3.8) but despite the upgrade our playbooks (which haven't changed) are taking 2 hours to execute instead of 1 hour.
Has anyone encountered this kind of slowdown with ansible with or without mitogen?
Mitogen team has stated that: Performance on Python 3 is significantly worse than on Python 2. While this has not yet been investigated, at least some of the regression appears to be part of the core library.
Any advice to get things sped up would be greatly appreciated, especially if others have noticed similar slowdowns.
Before python + ansible upgrade:
2023-07-17 16:30:36,782 p=12232 u=user n=ansible | Playbook run took 0 days, 1 hours, 2 minutes, 44 seconds
After python3.8 + ansible 5.4 upgrade:
2024-01-15 17:43:40,403 p=18143 u=user n=ansible | Playbook run took 0 days, 1 hours, 44 minutes, 56 seconds
Same playbook! Can anyone advise? Thanks
We have tried several versions of mitogen 0.3.3-0.3.5 which do help speed things up but it is not able to even put a dent in the slowdown we're experiencing since the python + ansible upgrade.
